# Can't save AppleScript file when created by touch

Tags: applescript, autosave

I'm used to create file using `touch` before opening them with `open`. But I came to this following problem :

When I do this with AppleScript files `AppleScript Editor` is able to open the file but unable to save the file. I get `The document "xxx.scpt" could not be saved`.

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work with .scpt files but it does work with .applescript files.

If you save an empty script as .scpt in AppleScript Editor, it looks like this:

```
hexdump -C Desktop/Untitled.scpt
00000000  46 61 73 64 55 41 53 20  31 2e 31 30 31 2e 31 30  |FasdUAS 1.101.10|
00000010  0e 00 00 00 04 0f ff ff  00 01 00 02 00 03 01 ff  |................|
00000020  ff 00 00 0d 00 01 00 03  6c 00 02 00 00 00 04 00  |........l.......|
00000030  04 ff fe ff fd 0d 00 04  00 03 52 00 00 00 00 00  |..........R.....|
00000040  04 ff fc 00 05 ff fb 0a  ff fc 00 18 2e 61 73 63  |.............asc|
00000050  72 65 72 72 20 2a 2a 2a  2a 00 00 00 00 00 00 90  |rerr ****.......|
00000060  00 2a 2a 2a 2a 0d 00 05  00 01 6d 00 00 00 02 00  |.****.....m.....|
00000070  03 00 06 0e 00 06 00 01  b1 00 07 11 00 07 00 74  |...............t|
00000080  00 54 00 68 00 69 00 73  00 20 00 73 00 63 00 72  |.T.h.i.s. .s.c.r|
00000090  00 69 00 70 00 74 00 20  00 63 00 6f 00 6e 00 74  |.i.p.t. .c.o.n.t|
000000a0  00 61 00 69 00 6e 00 73  00 20 00 75 00 6e 00 63  |.a.i.n.s. .u.n.c|
000000b0  00 6f 00 6d 00 70 00 69  00 6c 00 65 00 64 00 20  |.o.m.p.i.l.e.d. |
000000c0  00 63 00 68 00 61 00 6e  00 67 00 65 00 73 00 20  |.c.h.a.n.g.e.s. |
000000d0  00 61 00 6e 00 64 00 20  00 63 00 61 00 6e 00 6e  |.a.n.d. .c.a.n.n|
000000e0  00 6f 00 74 00 20 00 62  00 65 00 20 00 72 00 75  |.o.t. .b.e. .r.u|
000000f0  00 6e 00 2e 02 ff fb 00  00 01 ff fe 00 00 01 ff  |.n..............|
00000100  fd 00 00 0e 00 02 00 00  0f 10 00 03 00 03 ff fa  |................|
00000110  00 08 00 09 01 ff fa 00  00 10 00 08 00 01 ff f9  |................|
00000120  0a ff f9 00 18 2e 61 65  76 74 6f 61 70 70 6e 75  |......aevtoappnu|
00000130  6c 6c 00 00 80 00 00 00  90 00 2a 2a 2a 2a 0e 00  |ll........****..|
00000140  09 00 07 10 ff f8 00 0a  ff f7 ff f6 00 0b 00 0c  |................|
00000150  ff f5 0a ff f8 00 18 2e  61 65 76 74 6f 61 70 70  |........aevtoapp|
00000160  6e 75 6c 6c 00 00 80 00  00 00 90 00 2a 2a 2a 2a  |null........****|
00000170  0d 00 0a 00 01 6b 00 00  00 00 00 04 00 0d 02 00  |.....k..........|
00000180  0d 00 02 00 01 ff f4 02  ff f4 00 00 01 ff f7 00  |................|
00000190  00 02 ff f6 00 00 10 00  0b 00 00 10 00 0c 00 01  |................|
000001a0  00 06 11 ff f5 00 05 29  6a e0 15 0f 61 73 63 72  |.......)j...ascr|
000001b0  00 01 00 0c fa de de ad                           |........|
000001b8
```

You can create a new .scpt file with osacompile:

```
osacompile -e \"\" -o new.scpt
```

Comment: Yeah right, I forgot the .scpt files where compiled files !