# AppleScript editor cannot save .scpt file

Tags: applescript, file

I've created a simple AppleScript .scpt file, using TextEdit.

If I now open it with AppleScript editor, I can run it. But when I try to modify and save it, I get the following error:

[image]

It's frustrating that such a basic operation has got me completely stuck.

What is going wrong?

Comment: To which folder/directory are you trying to save it to?

Comment: to ~/Desktop/Foo/

Comment: I assume the folder exists and you have write access. Did you try another folder? Or creating a simple text file and store it there?

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work by creating a new file, pasting the contents in, saving. Still not sure why it won't save a document created by another editor.

Comment: Was the document still open in the other editor as well?

Comment: I was facing the same problem. Essentially, both you and me are creating **non-compiled** `.scpt` files by hand when this **is** a compiled file format (contrary to `.applescript`). Lri gives the right answer [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112072/cant-save-applescript-file-when-created-by-touch).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because `.scpt` extension is used for compiled scripts, just use `.applescript` extension and it will work just file.

Yet another example of the stupid coded error messages.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @sorin's answer, the most likely cause for this error is that you do not have permission to save scripts.
By default only **system** is allowed the create new scripts.

The solution is to enable write access for yourself.

Open Finder
Go to folder: /Library
Right click on the Scripts folder

[image]

<kbd>Get Info</kbd>
expand <kbd>v Sharing & Permissions:</kbd>

[image]

Click on the  lock to allow changes.
Add <kbd>+</kbd> a user (either Administrator, or your own user account)
and give that user <kbd>Read & Write</kbd> permissions.

Finally,
[image]

Click on the <kbd>(...)V</kbd> and <kbd>Apply to enclosed items...</kbd>

You will now be able to save new scripts.