# Why am I getting "Error -1,752" when trying to save in Script Editor?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to edit a script in ~/Library/Scripts/Applications/Mail. When I attempt to save from Script Editor I get **The document "Reply.scpt" could not be saved. (Error -1,752)**. It doesn't seem to be a permissions issue because I can edit and save the file in BBEdit (it's a plain text file).

I'm running Script Editor 2.8.1 under OS X 10.11.1 on a late 2015 iMac.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that the file is a plain text file. When I originally created the file in 2007, Script Editor could apparently save uncompiled `.scpt` files. Now, however, as described  in [Can't save AppleScript file when created by touch](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112072/cant-save-applescript-file-when-created-by-touch), `.scpt` files must be compiled. Uncompiled files can be saved with the `.applescript` extension.

I know this is nearly a duplicate of the question linked above, but I added it because as of OS X 10.11 El Capitan Script Editor gives an error number for this problem. I couldn't find any other references to this error number so I thought it was worthwhile to get the error number in a question title.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It makes sense and the problem is so frustrating and opaque.